# How to create Work flow with custom controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create a work flow with some custom controls and control lines. For the same i want to create my own editor to edit / Create work flow.
Can some one suggest where i can start / provide some references to start.

Thanks.

Comment: What specific does work flow do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too broad to give it a good and simple answer without writing a book. My advice is to split your project into sub tasks:

1. Create a control that e.g. looks like a box that shows some editable information (e.g. name)
2. Create a canvas area and place the control on it
3. Add Drag&Drop  to the control so the user can drag it across the
   canvas area
4. Add a second control and draw a line between them.
5. Create an UI to add an arbitrary number of controls to the canvas (e.g. via Drag&Drop)
6. Add commands to the control that represent the action (could use
   `ICommand`)
7. Create a workflow manager that interprets and executes the commands
   in the defined order
8. Extend the editor e.g. to enable the user to reconnect the lines or
   to add rules and priorities to the control or even to choose a set of commands from a pool and assign them to the control
9. Make everything look nice

Now that you have separate tasks, you can focus on each and research them individually. Step by step. Your questions therefore become more precise and easier to answer (for yourself and others).

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel?

You could re host the windows workflow designer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/samples/designer-rehosting

I've seen other articles talk about this in more detail but I couldn't immediately find them and you could of course just search yourself.

There is a huge amount of functionality in that thing which would take you forever to replicate.